Blazor Server with AntDesign Blazor - No suitable constructor was found for entity type 'RenderFragment'
I'm using Antdesign Blazor for my project in Asp.net Core bLazor Server.
Everything was perfect until I start adding Models and integrating it with EntityFramework.
This is my Program.cs
using AntDesign.ProLayout;
using iMonitor5.Data;
using iMonitor5.Pages.Account;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddAntDesign();
//builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient
//{
//    BaseAddress = new Uri(sp.GetService<NavigationManager>()!.BaseUri)
//});
builder.Services.Configure<ProSettings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("ProSettings"));
builder.Services.AddInteractiveStringLocalizer();
builder.Services.AddLocalization();
//builder.Services.AddScoped<IChartService, ChartService>();
//builder.Services.AddScoped<IProjectService, ProjectService>();
//builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
//builder.Services.AddScoped<IAccountService, AccountService>();
//builder.Services.AddScoped<IProfileService, ProfileService>();


builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IdentityUserAccessor>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IdentityRedirectManager>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, IdentityRevalidatingAuthenticationStateProvider>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
})
    .AddIdentityCookies();



var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("SQLiteDatabaseContext") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DatabaseContext' not found.");
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>(options => {
    options.UseSqlite(connectionString);
});

builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddSignInManager()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();







var app = builder.Build();

using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

    var context = services.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
    context.Database.EnsureCreated();
    DbInitializer.Initialize(context);
}

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

//app.MapBlazorHub();
//app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

app.Run();

And this my ApplicationDbContext :
using iMonitor5.Models.ActiveDirectory;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace iMonitor5.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext: IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<ADDomain> ADDomains { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ADObject> ADObjects { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ADEventType> ADEventTypes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ADEvent> ADEvents { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ADChange> ADChanges { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ADAuditLog> ADAuditLogs { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<ADDomain>().ToTable(nameof(ADDomain));
            modelBuilder.Entity<ADObject>().ToTable(nameof(ADObject));
            modelBuilder.Entity<ADEventType>().ToTable(nameof(ADEventType));
            modelBuilder.Entity<ADEvent>().ToTable(nameof(ADEvent));
            modelBuilder.Entity<ADChange>().ToTable(nameof(ADChange));
            modelBuilder.Entity<ADAuditLog>().ToTable(nameof(ADAuditLog));


            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }


}

And ApplicationUser :
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace iMonitor5.Data
{
    // Add profile data for application users by adding properties to the ApplicationUser class
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {

    }
}

I've double checked every Class, there's no Property called RenderFragment.
This is the full error :
System.InvalidOperationException : 'No suitable constructor was found for entity type 'RenderFragment'. The following constructors had parameters that could not be bound to properties of the entity type: 
    Cannot bind 'object', 'method' in 'RenderFragment(object object, IntPtr method)'
Note that only mapped properties can be bound to constructor parameters. Navigations to related entities, including references to owned types, cannot be bound.'


Hi Nadjib, please search for RenderFragment globally and take a screenshot to share with us to see the search results.
